# Is there any way that I can directly turn the bitwise representation of an integer into a vector in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to turn the bitwise representation of an unsigned integer directly into a vector<int> or vector<bool> in c++

for example:

```cpp
unsigned un = 203;//bitwise representation: (multiple 0) 1100 1011
//……
//I want a vector like this:
vector<int> unv = {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1};
//or
vector<bool> unv2 = {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1};
```

is there any direct way in c++ to reach that?   (I'm not searching for the method of successive division )

Comment: Do you need `std::vector`? `std::bitset` seems to be more appropriate, the conversion is straightforward then. If you want to convert the bitset to a vector then without a loop, you can convert it to a string with `to_string` first, and finally convert the string to a vector with something like `std::transform`.

Comment: Wow thank you! I didn't know it before I am going to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the function `std::generate` from the standard library. Description of the function can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

This, we will use with a statefull Lambda and mask out bit by bit. The result will be stored in the `std::vector`

So, this is a typical one-liner. I am not sure, if this is "directly" enough for you. But as said. Only one statement . . .

Please see one of many possible solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    unsigned int un = 203u;

    // Create a std::vector, with the needed size
    std::vector<int> unv(std::ceil(std::log2(un)));
    std::vector<bool> unv2(std::ceil(std::log2(un)));

    // Generate the content for the vector
    std::generate(unv.rbegin(), unv.rend(), [&un, mask = 1u]() mutable{ int result = un & mask ? 1 : 0; mask <<= 1; return result; });
    std::generate(unv2.rbegin(), unv2.rend(), [&un, mask = 1u]() mutable { bool result = un & mask; mask <<= 1; return result; });

    // Show result
    for (const int i : unv) std::cout << i; std::cout << '\n';
    for (const bool i : unv) std::cout << std::boolalpha << i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```